# General solution of PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

### $\frac{\partial ^2 x}{\partial x^2}=3y \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+2x$

Letting $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=v$

$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=3yv+2x$

Integrating Factors

$e^{\int{3y \partial x}}=e^{3yx}$

$\therefore e^{3yx}v=\frac{2}{3y}\int{3xye^{3xy} \partial x}$

$v=\frac{2}{3y}+h(y)e^{-3xy}$

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}= A(y)+H(y)e^x$

$u=A(y)x+H(y) e^x +B(y)$

But that is not the answer.

Comment: The particular solution $2/3y$ is clearly wrong. That's where your mistake is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The particular solution $2/3y$ is clearly wrong. Instead it should read $$\frac{-2x}{3y}-\frac{2}{9y^2}.$$ 
Moreover the solution of the homogeneous equation $h(y)e^{-3xy}$ has the wrong sign. It should be $$h(y)e^{+3xy}.$$